# Can't print model summary using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Hello I am building a DQN model for reinforcement learning on cartpole and want to print my model summary like keras model.summary() function

Here is my model class.

```
class DQN():
    ''' Deep Q Neural Network class. '''
    def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, hidden_dim=64, lr=0.05):
            super(DQN, self).__init__()
            self.criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
            self.model = torch.nn.Sequential(
                            torch.nn.Linear(state_dim, hidden_dim),
                            torch.nn.ReLU(),
                            torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim*2),
                            torch.nn.ReLU(),
                            torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2, action_dim)
                    )
            self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr)



    def update(self, state, y):
        """Update the weights of the network given a training sample. """
        y_pred = self.model(torch.Tensor(state))
        loss = self.criterion(y_pred, Variable(torch.Tensor(y)))
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()


    def predict(self, state):
        """ Compute Q values for all actions using the DQL. """
        with torch.no_grad():
            return self.model(torch.Tensor(state))
```

Here is the model instance with the parameters passed.

```
# Number of states = 4
n_state = env.observation_space.shape[0]
# Number of actions = 2
n_action = env.action_space.n
# Number of episodes
episodes = 150
# Number of hidden nodes in the DQN
n_hidden = 50
# Learning rate
lr = 0.001


simple_dqn = DQN(n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr)
```

I tried using torchinfo summary

```
from torchinfo import summary
simple_dqn = DQN(n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr)
summary(simple_dqn, input_size=(4, 2, 50))
```

But I get the following error

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py in forward_pass(model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, mode, **kwargs)
    286             if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
--> 287                 _ = model.to(device)(*x, **kwargs)
    288             elif isinstance(x, dict):

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1147 
-> 1148         result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1149         if _global_forward_hooks or self._forward_hooks:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _forward_unimplemented(self, *input)
    200     """
--> 201     raise NotImplementedError(f"Module [{type(self).__name__}] is missing the required \"forward\" function")
    202 

NotImplementedError: Module [DQN] is missing the required "forward" function

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ee921f7e5cb5> in <module>
      1 from torchinfo import summary
      2 simple_dqn = DQN(n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr)
----> 3 summary(simple_dqn, input_size=(4, 2, 50))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py in summary(model, input_size, input_data, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, col_names, col_width, depth, device, dtypes, mode, row_settings, verbose, **kwargs)
    216     )
    217     summary_list = forward_pass(
--> 218         model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, model_mode, **kwargs
    219     )
    220     formatting = FormattingOptions(depth, verbose, columns, col_width, rows)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py in forward_pass(model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, mode, **kwargs)
    297             "Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. "
    298             f"Executed layers up to: {executed_layers}"
--> 299         ) from e
    300     finally:
    301         if hooks:

RuntimeError: Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. Executed layers up to: []
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stack trace , you can see it throws this error at the beginning.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _forward_unimplemented(self, *input)
    200     """
--> 201     raise NotImplementedError(f"Module [{type(self).__name__}] is missing the required \"forward\" function")
    202 

NotImplementedError: Module [DQN] is missing the required "forward" function
```

This is the main error you should be looking at. Which is that you are missing the forward function your model should have. Here is an example of how you would implement it.

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(torch.nn.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(torch.nn.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
    x = torch.nn.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = torch.nn.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using your forward function code gives the error of AttributeError: 'DQN' object has no attribute 'pool' in relation to self.pool

Comment: I got the code from somewhere the main idea I was trying to say is you are missing your forward function . You are supposed to change it according to your need. Did you check the pytorch documentation on this link?

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html

Answer (score 0):

summary() takes in a model as its first parameter. simple_dqn is not a model, it's your custom class. Try passing simple_dqn.model (i.e. summary(simple_dqn.model, input_size=(4, 2, 50)))